# Como fazer um upload de arquivo utilizando lftp?

Tags: linux, ftp

Como posso enviar um arquivo da minha máquina local para o servidor remoto utilizando o `lftp`?

Comment: http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/setup-lftp-command-line-ftp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para enviar um arquivo para o servidor remoto, primeiro execute o `lftp`

```
lftp
```

o prompt do `lftp` irá abrir

```
lftp :~>
```

agora é possível realizar conexão com o servidor remoto

```
lftp :~>  open -u "usuario","senha" host;
```

o console informará qual servidor você está conectado

```
lftp user@host:~>
```

para enviar o arquivo execute o seguinte comando

```
lftp user@host:~> put -O pasta/de/destino /caminho/local/ate/arquivo.zip;
```

após a conclusão do envio, execute o comando `bye` para fechar o prompt do `lftp`

```
lftp user@host:~> bye;
```

o arquivo.zip agora estará na pasta de destino no servidor remoto.

Realizei este exemplo utilizando Ubuntu 16.